# How do i consume an Api in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to build a React application. I have a custom Api build. What i am trying is, to use the api in React but it does not work. It is not showing the data, the id,name,lastname and age of the patient.

This is a home.js component how it looks:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Home extends React.Component{

  state={
    patientData:[]
  }

      componentWillMount(){

        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/clinicalservices/api/patients').then(res=>{
          const patientData = res.data;
          this.setState({patientData})

        })

      }

      render(){
        return (<div>
        <h2>Patient:</h2>
        <table align='center'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
          </thead> 
          <tbody>
            {this.state.patientData.map(patient=><RowCreator item={patient}/>)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <Link to={'/addPatient'}><font size="5">Register Patient</font></Link>
        </div>)
      }
    }

    class RowCreator extends React.Component{
      render(){
        var patient = this.props.item;
        return <tr>
          <td>{patient.id}</td>
          <td>{patient.firstName}</td>
          <td>{patient.lastName}</td>
          <td>{patient.age}</td>
          <td><Link to={'/patiendDetails/'+patient.id}>Add Data</Link></td>
          <td><Link to={'/analyze/'+patient.id}>Analyze</Link></td>
        </tr>
      }
    }
```

export default Home;

This is my Api data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "lastName": "John",
        "firstName": "Mccain",
        "age": 52,
        
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "lastName": "Siva",
        "firstName": "Shankar",
        "age": 32,
        
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "lastName": "Anthony",
        "firstName": "Simon",
        "age": 22,
       
    }
]
```

What i am getting when i start a React App:
[Link to React app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SCuS.png)

it does not show tha data

Comment: Did you check the network tab in your browser to make sure you are actually getting a successful response when making the HTTP request to your API? Also, did you check the response to make sure the data you are getting looks as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the backend i added @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000") to controllers package in my API and now the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the return method of `RowCreator` is just returning an `<tr>` and not the whole row as you may think.

Try with proper format:

```
class RowCreator extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var patient = this.props.item;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{patient.id}</td>
        <td>{patient.firstName}</td>
        <td>{patient.lastName}</td>
        <td>{patient.age}</td>
        <td>
          <Link to={"/patiendDetails/" + patient.id}>Add Data</Link>
        </td>
        <td>
          <Link to={"/analyze/" + patient.id}>Analyze</Link>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

Also have in mind that every `RowCreator` should have an unique key as identifier in order to make it easier for React to manage the list.

```
<RowCreator item={patient} key={patient.id} />
```

Plus, the recommended way to start fetching data in React is in the `componentDidMount` method

Comment: There is no issue with the return statement, the <tr> (up to the close) is read as one expression. The issue is the other concern you pointed out and OP needs to use `componentDidMount`. `componentWillMount` is unsafe and should have no side effects. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount .  Also, OP should add a Key property to those RowCreator elements. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html